# Laravel throws InvalidArgumentException View [.profilePage.{user}] not found

Tags: php, laravel

Good night, I'm working on a Laravel project.
I did a "Your Profile" button that redirects you to your profile, but i have an InvalidArgumentException: View [.profilePage.{user}] not found.

my UserPolicy.php function:

```php
    public function Owner(User $user,User $destinationUser){
        return $user->id == $destinationUser->id;
    }
```

my UserController.php

```php
    public function profile(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('Owner', $user);
        return view('/profilePage/{user}', compact('user',$user));

    }
```

my web.php

```php
Route::get('/profilePage/{user}', 'UserController@profile');
```

my navbar.blade.php layout:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/profilePage/'.Auth::user()->id)}}">Your profile</a>
```

I don't know where is the error and I'm needing help.

Comment: `view('/profilePage/{user}')`  ... you have a view file literally named `'{user}.blade.php'` ?

Comment: No, the user profile's page file name is ProfilePage.blade.php

Comment: then it would be `view('ProfilePage', ...)` .. it is referencing a file, not a route   .... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#creating-views reread that section and it will make more sense

Comment: The thing is that I want the link shows http://127.0.0.1:8000/profilePage/1, where 1 is your profile number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your view not found issue you need to pass the actual view name you want to be returned, without the extension:

```
return view('ProfilePage', compact('user'));
```

Your link is correct in the view though:

```
url('profilePage/'. Auth::user()->id)
```

will generate a URL like: `http://yoursite.test/profilePage/1`

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Views - Creating Views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#creating-views) `view`

[Laravel 6.x Docs - URLs - Generating Basic URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#generating-basic-urls) `url`

[PHP Manual - Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) `compact`

Answer (score 0):

The line `return view('/profilePage/{user}', compact('user',$user));` is incorrect.

view() accepts a path/file in dot notation format.

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
public function profile(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('Owner', $user);
    return view('profile.show', compact('user'));

}
```

The above code would return the view in `resources\views\profile\show.blade.php`

The route entry itself `Route::get('/profilePage/{user}', 'UserController@profile');` will create the actual endpoint `/profilePage/1`, not the view returned in the controller.